how to enable Publicly accessible to yes in Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service)
I am trying to set up RDS on AWS, Amazon RDS (Relational Database Service) . But I am not able to change the default Publicly accessible to yes .
Publicly accessible is No by default. I couldn't find any option to change the default option.

Is the database already running, or are you just trying to launch it?

When launching the Amazon RDS database, be sure to select Standard create (not Easy create).
The option will appear towards the bottom:

If the database is already running, use the Modify command to change this setting. It will require a restart of the database server.
